# Broken y-axis histogram in R? (again)

Tags: r, histogram, axis

I've been working on putting together a broken y-axis histogram, in order to display one very tall bar while not having the other bars invisible.  In particular, I would like to be able to control not only what the tics are on the x-axis (they need to show the count bins from the histogram, not just the axes), but also how many tics there are on the x-axis.

This question got me started, though I had to figure out on my own how to use the `xtics` option in `plotrix`'s `gap.barplot` to show the histogram bins:
[Put a break in the Y-Axis of a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504804/put-a-break-in-the-y-axis-of-a-histogram/25161840#25161840)

However, I still cannot figure out a way to plot a broken y-axis histogram without having it try to plot a tic for every single bin.  Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a possible solution to the problem:

would it be possible to just log transform your variables and plot the histogram of the log transformation? this is what i would usually do in your situation. You can apply this transformations directly in `ggplot2` by adding `scale_x_log10()` or `scale_y_log10()` to your graph object. for more information see here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html

Comment: A histogram is used to show the distribution of values. A broken axis distorts this.

Comment: You need to show code and a sample dataset. Then we could see what problem you are having with the "x-axis" which is usually managed with a 'breaks' argument.

Comment: If you're determined to break the axis, you should also [break the bar](http://peltiertech.com/images/2011-11/Ybroken.png).

Answer (score 0):

The broken part of the x or y axis, mostly at y axis is known as commonly referred as ‘axis break’, or very rarely as the ‘Tresman mark’. It represents discontinuity in the axis.

For example, your pattern goes in 5s, like 10-15, and suddenly becomes 17-20, you can use this.