# R histogram-reducing y range

Tags: r, graph, draw, histogram, bar-chart

I'm trying to draw a graph looks like below using r, and was wondering if there is a way to

1) omit the lower range of y values, but still start from 0.

2) Also, instead of numerical values, how do I label each bar in the histogram with texts?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504804/put-a-break-in-the-y-axis-of-a-histogram Not sure about the squiggly lines though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worth-a-read answer in the comments was using the same example of plotrix::gap.barplot that I picked but I've been working on those "squiggly lines":

```
require(plotrix)
twogrp<-c(rnorm(10)+4,rnorm(10)+20)
gap.barplot(twogrp, gap=c(8,16), xlab="Index", ytics=c(3,6,17,20),
                   ylab="Group values", main="Barplot with gap")
polygon(y=c( 7.5+c(-1,1)*.2*rep(1,length(twogrp)+2),  
             8.5+ c(-1,1)*.2*rep(1,length(twogrp)+2) ) ,
        x=c(0,seq_along(twogrp), rep(length(twogrp)+1, 2), # going to the right...
              rev(seq_along(twogrp)) ,0) ,                # and coming back to the left
        col="white", border="white")  # could also try border="lightblue"
```

[image]

There is also an `axis.break` function in plotrix that will give you the annotation on the axis. You would use the `text` function for labels inside the plot area.