# Is it possible draw a histogram with 2 gaps in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, plotrix

I need to change this plot in a histogrm keeping the 2 gaps. Is it possible?[image]

The code of this plot is:

```
gap.plot(tmp,gap=c(200,400,500,2800), type="p", xlab="Index", 
     ytics=c(25, 50, 75,100, 150, 450, 2860),ylab="Group values",
     main="Barplot with gap")
```

with tmp = 2860  436  191   88   34   21    9    4    1    0    0    0    0    0    1

The result should be like the follow histogram but with the 2 gaps.
[image]

The question [Put a break in the Y-Axis of a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504804/put-a-break-in-the-y-axis-of-a-histogram) explains how to put 1 (one) gap. I already did this and my question is about 2 (two) gaps. `gap.barplot` from the plotrix package does not support multiple gaps.

Comment: He's asking for a gap.barplot with two gaps, not only one, as the question they pointed did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504804/put-a-break-in-the-y-axis-of-a-histogram As far as I know you cannot introduce two gaps using a gap.barplot using plotrix, but maybe there's a way to do it.

Comment: @Simone11489 if the answer of the duplicate question does not fully solve your problem then ask a new question and point out clearly that it is not a duplicate and why so.