# Broken barplot using R/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with scaling my barplots when there are some extreme counts. As it goes up much higher it is extremely difficult to see the lower counts and compare them on a plot.

I would like to break the barplot in order to rescale it (I know rescaling is bad plotting but I only want to do it when required).

Something similar to the following image that I found in the link attached would great.

[image: Broken barPlot]

https://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/broken-column-and-bar-charts/

Comment: You could consider making a facet plot with free scales. Or you could create one plot for each series and arrange them using grid.arrange.

Comment: It kinda defies the purpose of the bar plot. If you want to go _there_ why not use a log scale?

Comment: This post can partially help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612348/break-x-axis-in-r

Comment: I've previously provided [an answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508395/1305688) to almost the same question.