# Combined ggplot and plotrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotrix

I need to add a Y axis break to a plot I made in ggplot. Is it possible to use the gap.barplot function in plotrix in a graph in ggplot? When I try, it cancels everything I did in ggplot and plots just the gap.barplot bit.

Thank you

Barbara

Comment: As far as I'm aware `plotrix` uses base graphics while `ggplot` uses the `grid` graphics system. This means `plotrix` functions will not work with `ggplot` graphs.

Comment: Given everything I know about ggplot, I imagine that it has been made *incredibly* difficult to add a break in the axis. Hadley Wickham is fairly serious about plot integrity, and has intentionally not implemented related features (e.g., dual axes). Breaking the y-axis is generally a very bad idea. That said, if you have a particular use case, someone here may be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately NO.
They work on two different "worlds".
I've been trying a lot but it seems (just like @Mark Peterson wrote) that doing this in ggplot is nearly impossible on purpose

You should look into these questions and answers which are very similiar:
[Using ggplot2, can I insert a break in the axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis)
[Broken barplot using R/ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809865/broken-barplot-using-r-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1)