# How to highlight non-zero start of y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to replicate the fertility graph from gapminder as good as I can in `ggplot`:

[image: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.gapminder.org/GapminderMedia/wp-uploads/20180313124853/babies-per-woman-1024x645.png]

I have:

```
fertility <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcoKuehne/marcokuehne.github.io/main/data/Gapminder/tfr-by-gapminder-v12-20171212.csv", sep = ";")

# manipulate
library(tidyverse)
fertility <- fertility %>% 
  select(!c(geo.name, geo, indicator)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  gather(var, value, -rowname) %>% 
  spread(rowname, value) %>% 
  rename(year = var, fert = `1`) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 301) 

fertility[,1:2] <- sapply(fertility[,1:2],FUN=as.numeric)

fertility1 <- fertility[1:217,]
fertility2 <- fertility[218:301,]

# visualize 
ggplot(data = fertility, aes(x=year, y=fert)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=year[1], y=fert[1]), size = 4) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=year[1], y=fert[1], label = year[1]), vjust = 2.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=year[165], y=fert[165]), size = 4) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=year[165], y=fert[165], label = year[165]), vjust = -3, hjust = -0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x=year[165], y=fert[165], label = "5 births"), vjust = -1.5, hjust = -0.2) +
  #geom_point(aes(x=year[217], y=fert[217]), size = 4) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=year[217], y=fert[217], label = year[217]), vjust = -3) +
  geom_text(aes(x=year[217], y=fert[217], label = "2.5 births"), vjust = -1.5) +
  geom_line(data = fertility1, size=1.3, arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.30,"cm"), ends="last", type = "closed")) +
  geom_line(data = fertility2, size=1.3,linetype="dashed") +
  labs(title = "Average Number Of Babies Per Woman From 1800 to Today",
       caption = "Source: Gapminder based on UN-Pop", y="", x="") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

I have some troubles with the linewidth of `geom_line()`. And I am looking for a compromise between `geom_line()` and `geom_smooth()` to make the line plot just a little bit more smooth.

But my major concern at the moment is the broken y-axis. When y-axis does not start at zero, I'd like to hightlight this as in the gapminder graph.

Comment: If you use `method = "loess"` you can adjust the smoothness using the `span` parameter.

Comment: There are several packages that implement axis gaps for ggplot2.

Comment: @Roland can you please name one? E.g. `plotrix` does the job on its own but does not work with `ggplot` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786790/combined-ggplot-and-plotrix

Comment: E.g., https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gggap/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @Roland you could smooth your lines using a `loess` curve. However, instead of trying with `geom_smooth` I would suggest to do the calculation outside of ggplot as we need the smoothed values also for the points and the labels and we also need the same values for "both" lines.

For your axis break a simple approach would be to use two `annotate`, one to place the `segment`s, one to add the filled "gap" for which I use a `ribbon`. This requires some fiddling to get the right positions, to fix the limits and to set `clip="off"`. Also note that I added the axis lines via `geom_h/vline` so that the annotate layers could be placed on top of the axes.

Finally, I slightly adjusted your data wrangling code, use a dataset to place the labels and points and instead of using `vjust` I shift the labels directly via the `y` position.

**EDIT** For the final touch I added some additional styling.

```
# manipulate
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(hrbrthemes)

font_add_google("lato", "Lato", regular.wt = 900)

fertility <- fertility %>%
  select(!c(geo.name, geo, indicator)) %>%
  mutate(
    across(-indicator.name, as.character),
    across(-indicator.name, ~ readr::parse_number(.x, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-indicator.name, names_to = "year", values_to = "fert", names_prefix = "X") %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) |>
  mutate(fert_smooth = predict(loess(fert ~ year, span = .05)))

fertility_to_high <- fertility |>
  filter(year %in% c(1800, 1964, 2016)) |>
  mutate(
    label = if_else(!year == 1800, paste0(year, "<br>**", round(fert, 1), " births**"), as.character(year)),
    hjust = if_else(year == 2016, 0, .5)
  )

ggplot(data = fertility, aes(x = year, y = fert_smooth)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(fertility_to_high, year == 1964), size = 10, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = subset(fertility_to_high, year != 2016), size = 3) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(data = fertility_to_high, aes(y = fert + .15, label = label, hjust = hjust), 
                        vjust = 0, label.colour = NA, family = font_rc, lineheight = 1.2) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.3, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = ~ subset(.x, year <= 2016), linewidth = 1.3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.30, "cm"), ends = "last", type = "closed")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1785) +
  annotate(geom = "ribbon", x = c(1780, 1790) - .55, ymin = c(1.3, 1.5), ymax = c(1.5, 1.7), fill = "white") +
  annotate(
    geom = "segment",
    x = c(1780, 1780) - .5, xend = c(1790, 1790) - .5,
    y = c(1.3, 1.5), yend = c(1.5, 1.7), linewidth = 1
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:6, labels = c(0, 2:6), expand = c(0, .0, .05, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0, 0, 0)) +
  labs(
    title = toupper("Average Number Of Babies Per Woman From 1800 to Today"),
    caption = "Source: Gapminder based on UN-Pop", y = "", x = ""
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(1, 6), xlim = c(1800, NA)) +
  theme_bw(base_family = font_rc, base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(family = "lato"),
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.caption = element_text(family = "lato", color = "grey40"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = c(rep(.5, 3), 1))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Great to know how to skipping values in y axis, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The key is to add:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6.2), expand = c(0, 0))
```

It tells R to limit the y range within 0 and 6.2, and show no gap beyond these two values.
The sample code below may work for you, after running it, you will get:

[image]

```
fertility <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcoKuehne/marcokuehne.github.io/main/data/Gapminder/tfr-by-gapminder-v12-20171212.csv", sep = ";")

# manipulate
library(tidyverse)
fertility <- fertility |>  
  select(!c(geo.name, geo, indicator)) |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  rownames_to_column() |> 
  slice(-1) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  rename(c(year = rowname, fert = V1)) |> 
  mutate(year = str_remove(year, "X"),
         year = as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1)),
         fert = str_replace(fert, ",", "."),
         fert = as.numeric(fert),
         fert_1 = case_when(year <= as.Date("2017-01-01") ~ fert, 
                            TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)),
         fert_2 = case_when(year >= as.Date("2017-01-01") ~ fert, 
                            TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)),
         arr_data = case_when((year > as.Date("2014-01-01") & year < "2018-01-01") ~ fert, 
                              TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA))) 
  

fertility |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, 
             y = fert)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = year, 
                  y = fert_1, 
                  group = 1),
              span = 0.11,
              se = FALSE,
              colour = "black",
              size = 1.5) +
  
  geom_line(aes(x = year, 
                y = arr_data),
            arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.4,"cm"), 
                          ends="last", 
                          type = "closed"), 
            size = 3) +
  
  geom_line(aes(x = year, 
                y = fert_2, 
                group = 1),
            linetype = 2,
            size = 1.5) +
  
  
  geom_point(aes(x = year[1], 
                 y = fert[1]),
             size = 5) +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[1], 
           y = fertility$fert[1], 
           label = "1800",
           size = 4,
           vjust = -1.2) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = fertility$year[166], 
                 y = fertility$fert[166]),
             shape = 1,
             size = 12,
             colour = "grey50") +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[166], 
           y = fertility$fert[166], 
           label = "1965",
           size = 4,
           vjust = -4.2) +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[166], 
           y = fertility$fert[166], 
           label = "5 births",
           size = 5,
           fontface = "bold",
           vjust = -2) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = fertility$year[166], 
                 y = fertility$fert[166]),
             shape = 1,
             size = 12,
             colour = "grey50") +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[166], 
           y = fertility$fert[166], 
           label = "1965",
           size = 4,
           vjust = -4.2) +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[166], 
           y = fertility$fert[166], 
           label = "5 births",
           size = 5,
           fontface = "bold",
           vjust = -2) +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[218], 
           y = fertility$fert[218], 
           label = "2017",
           size = 4,
           vjust = -4.2,
           hjust = 0) +
  
  annotate(geom = "text", 
           x = fertility$year[218], 
           y = fertility$fert[218], 
           label = "2.5 births",
           size = 5,
           fontface = "bold",
           vjust = -2,
           hjust = 0) +
  
  
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_date(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.02, 0))) +
  
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
    
    
    axis.line.x = element_line(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(),
    
    plot.caption = element_text(colour = "grey50"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16,
                              hjust = 0.5,
                              face = "bold"),
    
    
    plot.margin = margin(r = 18,
                         t = 5,
                         l = 5,
                         b = 2)
  ) +
  
  labs(
    title = "AVERAGE NUMBER OF BABIES PER WOMAN FROM 1800 TO TODAY",
    x = element_blank(),
    y = element_blank(),
    caption = "Source:Gapminder[7] based on UN-Pop[3]"
  )
```