# overlay rotated density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to overlap rotated density plot onto the original scatterplot. Here are 2 plots I have:

```
require(ggplot2); set.seed(1);

df1 <- data.frame(ID=paste0('ID',1:1000), value=rnorm(1000,500,100))

p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=reorder(ID, value), y=value)) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha = 0.7)+
  coord_trans(y="log10") 

p2 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=value)) +
  coord_trans(x="log10") +
  geom_density() +
  coord_flip()

p1
p2
```

[image: sample plots]

First, there's a little problem with the density plot that its vertical axis is not log10-transformed. But main issue is that I can't find how to draw it on the previous plot keeping correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using coord_flip on your second plot you are effectively trying to plot two different values onto the same x axis (density and ID). There are plenty of posts discouraging this, here's one for example: [How do I plot points with two different y-axis ranges on the same panel in the same X axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735176/how-do-i-plot-points-with-two-different-y-axis-ranges-on-the-same-panel-in-the-s).