# Clip marks at the end of axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

`R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)  Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)`

I am working on a histogram with `ggplot2`. Since I have heavily tailed data, I would like to use axis "clip marks" at the end of the x-axis in ggplot like in the following example. (not the red 0.95 quantile but the small black clip marks at the end of the x axis)

The question is not about a break within the axis as asked in [Using ggplot2, can I insert a break in the axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) but about clipping of the end of the axis and adding a marker, that the reader of the plot can immediately see, that the observed data exceeds the axis. This example has two little tilted parallel slashes at the end of the x-axis. This is what I would like to achieve on a ggplot plot.

```
require(plotrix)
x <- rbeta(10000, 1, 7)
hist(x, xlim=c(0,0.4))
axis.break(1,0.405)
```

[image]

Is there a possibility to get similar axis break marks with ggplot? I had the idea to work with geom_segment but I did not achieve any good solution, since it always depends on the ratio of the x and y axis values.

```
ggplot()+
      geom_histogram(aes(x=x), binwidth = 0.05)+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.45))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: look at `geom_vline`

Comment: @Davide Passaretti  The question is not about the red line but the small break marks at the end of the x axis.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) suggests it cannot be done. They also suggests other alternatives (e.g. log axis).

Comment: @ddiez The question is not about a break within the axis as asked in ["Using ggplot2, can I insert a break in the axis?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) but about cutting of the end of the axis and add a marker that the reader of the plot can immediately see, that data has been clipped off.

Comment: Ah ok, understood now. I would suggest you change the plot because it is very misleading (that is, it contains a break in the axis and there are values beyond the red mark). Anyway, someone wrote an answer- hopefully is what you were looking for.

Comment: On a second thought, maybe i still don't understand. Do you want the red line or the little break marks in the axis?

Comment: I edited the question. It should be clear now. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT after comment.  Better?

```
ggplot()+  geom_histogram(aes(x=x), binwidth = 0.05, color = "grey30", fill = "white")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.405)) +
  theme_tufte() +
  labs(y = "Frequency") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.4, xend = 0.4, y = 0.01, yend = .99, colour = "red", label = "//", size =6)
```

[image]

Comment: That is not, what I was looking for. I edited the question. Now it should be clear. Sorry.

Comment: Actually a good and creative idea. I will try to implement it to my purpose.

Comment: Glad to help, even if I am slow to understand what you wanted.  :)  Possibly consider accepting the answer unless a better one comes along.

Comment: Did it. My mistake, question was formulated not very well by me.