# How to adjust facet size manually

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggproto

I have a faceted plot with very diverse data. So some facets have only 1 `x` value, but some others have 13 `x` values. I know there is the parameter `space='free'` which adjusts the width of each facet by the data it represents.

My question, is there a possibility to adjust this space manually? Since some of my facets are so small, it is no longer possible to read the labels in the facets. I made a little reproducible example to show what I mean.

```
df <- data.frame(labelx=rep(c('my long label','short'), c(2,26)),
                 labely=rep(c('a','b'), each=14),
                 x=c(letters[1:2],letters[1:26]),
                 y=LETTERS[6:7],
                 i=rnorm(28))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=i)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(labely~labelx, scales='free_x', space='free_x')
```

So depending on your screen, the `my long label` facet gets compressed and you can no longer read the label.

I found a post on the internet which seems to do exactly what I want to do, but this seems to no longer work in `ggplot2`. The post is from 2010.

https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/adjusting-the-relative-space-of-a-facet-grid/

He suggests to use `facet_grid(fac1 + fac2 ~ fac3 + fac4, widths = 1:4, heights = 4:1)`, so `widths` and `heights` to adjust each facet size manually.

Comment: My guess is that you would have to play around with `ggplotGrob`. Also, here is a link to the source code for the function. You might be able to work out what the "scales" argument  is doing and then use this knowledge to alter the final ggplot.  https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/facet-grid-.r#L314 Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can adjust the widths of a ggplot object using grid graphics

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=i)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(labely~labelx, scales='free_x', space='free_x')

library(grid)
gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g))
gt$widths[4] = 4*gt$widths[4]
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

With complex graphs with many elements, it can be slightly cumbersome to determine which width it is that you want to alter.  In this instance it was grid column 4 that needed to be expanded, but this will vary for different plots.  There are several ways to determine which one to change, but a fairly simple and good way is to use `gtable_show_layout` from the `gtable` package.

```
gtable_show_layout(gt)
```

produces the following image:

[image]

in which we can see that the left hand facet is in column number 4.  The first 3 columns provide room for the margin, the axis title and the axis labels+ticks. Column 5 is the space between the facets, column 6 is the right hand facet. Columns 7 through 12 are for the right hand facet labels, spaces, the legend, and the right margin.

An alternative to inspecting a graphical representation of the gtable is to simply inspect the table itself. In fact if you need to automate the process, this would be the way to do it.  So lets have a look at the TableGrob:

```
gt
# TableGrob (13 x 12) "layout": 25 grobs
#     z         cells       name                                   grob
# 1   0 ( 1-13, 1-12) background        rect[plot.background..rect.399]
# 2   1 ( 7- 7, 4- 4)  panel-1-1               gTree[panel-1.gTree.283]
# 3   1 ( 9- 9, 4- 4)  panel-2-1               gTree[panel-3.gTree.305]
# 4   1 ( 7- 7, 6- 6)  panel-1-2               gTree[panel-2.gTree.294]
# 5   1 ( 9- 9, 6- 6)  panel-2-2               gTree[panel-4.gTree.316]
# 6   3 ( 5- 5, 4- 4)   axis-t-1                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 7   3 ( 5- 5, 6- 6)   axis-t-2                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 8   3 (10-10, 4- 4)   axis-b-1    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.329]
# 9   3 (10-10, 6- 6)   axis-b-2    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.336]
# 10  3 ( 7- 7, 3- 3)   axis-l-1    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.343]
# 11  3 ( 9- 9, 3- 3)   axis-l-2    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.350]
# 12  3 ( 7- 7, 8- 8)   axis-r-1                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 13  3 ( 9- 9, 8- 8)   axis-r-2                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 14  2 ( 6- 6, 4- 4)  strip-t-1                          gtable[strip]
# 15  2 ( 6- 6, 6- 6)  strip-t-2                          gtable[strip]
# 16  2 ( 7- 7, 7- 7)  strip-r-1                          gtable[strip]
# 17  2 ( 9- 9, 7- 7)  strip-r-2                          gtable[strip]
# 18  4 ( 4- 4, 4- 6)     xlab-t                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 19  5 (11-11, 4- 6)     xlab-b titleGrob[axis.title.x..titleGrob.319]
# 20  6 ( 7- 9, 2- 2)     ylab-l titleGrob[axis.title.y..titleGrob.322]
# 21  7 ( 7- 9, 9- 9)     ylab-r                         zeroGrob[NULL]
# 22  8 ( 7- 9,11-11)  guide-box                      gtable[guide-box]
# 23  9 ( 3- 3, 4- 6)   subtitle  zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.396]
# 24 10 ( 2- 2, 4- 6)      title     zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.395]
# 25 11 (12-12, 4- 6)    caption   zeroGrob[plot.caption..zeroGrob.397]
```

The relevant bits are

```
#         cells       name  
# ( 7- 7, 4- 4)  panel-1-1      
# ( 9- 9, 4- 4)  panel-2-1              
# ( 6- 6, 4- 4)  strip-t-1
```

in which the names panel-x-y refer to panels in x, y coordinates, and the cells give the coordinates (as ranges) of that named panel in the table. So, for example, the top and bottom left-hand panels both are located in table cells with the column ranges `4- 4`. (only in column four, that is).  The left-hand top strip is also in cell column 4.

If you wanted to use this table to find the relevant width programmatically, rather than manually, (using the top left facet, ie `"panel-1-1"` as an example) you could use

```
gt$layout$l[grep('panel-1-1', gt$layout$name)]
# [1] 4
```

Comment: Can you explain, why it is the 4th index? My original figure is a bit more complicated and I also tried the `gig-lot_gtable`-approach, but creating gtables from the space-free and space-auto leads to the same `$widths` vector. I was trying to play with this for more than an hour.

Comment: @drmariod edited answer to provide some more info about this. Hope this helps.

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE IT!!! How is it possible to miss the `gtable` package!!! This saves lifetimes in fiddling with the figures! OH MY GOSH! Thanks!

Comment: Specially the `gtable_show_layout` function is cool! :-) I am totally flashed!

Answer (score 22):

Sorry for posting this years later, but I had this exact problem a while ago and wrote a function to make it easier. I thought it could help people here if I shared it. At it's core it is also setting widths/heights in the gtable, but it integrates at the facet level so that you can still add things. It lives in a package I wrote on github (EDIT: It's available on CRAN now). Note that you can also set absolute size with `grid::unit(..., "cm")` for example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

df <- data.frame(labelx=rep(c('my long label','short'), c(2,26)),
                 labely=rep(c('a','b'), each=14),
                 x=c(letters[1:2],letters[1:26]),
                 y=LETTERS[6:7],
                 i=rnorm(28))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=i)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(labely~labelx, scales='free_x', space='free_x') +
  force_panelsizes(cols = c(0.3, 1)) +
  theme_bw() # Just to show you can still add things
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This seems a lot easier than messing with values in the gtable!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It worked for me and it was very easy to implement.

Answer (score 9):

Ah yes very sad that functionality to set `widths` and `heights` in `facet_grid` is gone.

Another possible workaround without `ggplotGrob` is to set the text angle in `theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle...))` and facet text wrapping in `facet_grid(... labeller=label_wrap_gen(width...))`, e.g.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=i)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(labely~labelx, scales='free_x', space='free_x', labeller=label_wrap_gen(width = 10, multi_line = TRUE)) +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking on something like this, but it isn't an option for the original plot.

Answer (score 7):

In case you are interested in modifying `ggplot2` in more and other ways, **I recommend the vignette**:

```
vignette("extending-ggplot2")
```

Now for your problem at hand, I think the shortcut of a clean solution goes as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- data.frame(labelx = rep(c('my long label','short'), c(2,26)),
                 labely = rep(c('a','b'), each = 14),
                 x = c(letters[1:2], letters[1:26]),
                 y = LETTERS[6:7],
                 i = rnorm(28))

# ad-hoc replacement for the "draw_panels" method, sorry for the hundred lines of code...
# only modification is marked with a comment
draw_panels_new <- function(panels, layout, x_scales, y_scales, ranges, coord, data, theme, params) {
  cols <- which(layout$ROW == 1)
  rows <- which(layout$COL == 1)
  axes <- render_axes(ranges[cols], ranges[rows], coord, theme, transpose = TRUE)
  col_vars <- unique(layout[names(params$cols)])
  row_vars <- unique(layout[names(params$rows)])
  attr(col_vars, "type") <- "cols"
  attr(col_vars, "facet") <- "grid"
  attr(row_vars, "type") <- "rows"
  attr(row_vars, "facet") <- "grid"
  strips <- render_strips(col_vars, row_vars, params$labeller, theme)
  aspect_ratio <- theme$aspect.ratio
  if (is.null(aspect_ratio) && !params$free$x && !params$free$y) {
    aspect_ratio <- coord$aspect(ranges[[1]])
  }
  if (is.null(aspect_ratio)) {
    aspect_ratio <- 1
    respect <- FALSE
  } else {
    respect <- TRUE
  }
  ncol <- max(layout$COL)
  nrow <- max(layout$ROW)
  panel_table <- matrix(panels, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = TRUE)
  if (params$space_free$x) {
    ps <- layout$PANEL[layout$ROW == 1]
    widths <- vapply(ps, function(i) diff(ranges[[i]]$x.range), numeric(1))
    # replaced "widths" below with custom manual values c(1,4)
    panel_widths <- unit(c(1,4), "null")
  } else {
    panel_widths <- rep(unit(1, "null"), ncol)
  }
  if (params$space_free$y) {
    ps <- layout$PANEL[layout$COL == 1]
    heights <- vapply(ps, function(i) diff(ranges[[i]]$y.range), numeric(1))
    panel_heights <- unit(heights, "null")
  } else {
    panel_heights <- rep(unit(1 * aspect_ratio, "null"), 
                         nrow)
  }
  panel_table <- gtable_matrix("layout", panel_table, panel_widths, 
                               panel_heights, respect = respect, clip = "on", z = matrix(1, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow))
  panel_table$layout$name <- paste0("panel-", rep(seq_len(ncol), nrow), "-", rep(seq_len(nrow), each = ncol))
  panel_table <- gtable_add_col_space(panel_table, theme$panel.spacing.x %||% theme$panel.spacing)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_row_space(panel_table, theme$panel.spacing.y %||% theme$panel.spacing)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(axes$x$top), 0)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(axes$x$bottom), -1)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(axes$y$left), 0)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(axes$y$right), -1)
  panel_pos_col <- panel_cols(panel_table)
  panel_pos_rows <- panel_rows(panel_table)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$x$top, 1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "off", 
                                 name = paste0("axis-t-", seq_along(axes$x$top)), z = 3)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$x$bottom, -1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "off", 
                                 name = paste0("axis-b-", seq_along(axes$x$bottom)), z = 3)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 1, clip = "off", 
                                 name = paste0("axis-l-", seq_along(axes$y$left)), z = 3)
  panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -1, clip = "off", 
                                 name = paste0("axis-r-", seq_along(axes$y$right)), z = 3)
  switch_x <- !is.null(params$switch) && params$switch %in% c("both", "x")
  switch_y <- !is.null(params$switch) && params$switch %in% c("both", "y")
  inside_x <- (theme$strip.placement.x %||% theme$strip.placement %||% "inside") == "inside"
  inside_y <- (theme$strip.placement.y %||% theme$strip.placement %||% "inside") == "inside"
  strip_padding <- convertUnit(theme$strip.switch.pad.grid, "cm")
  panel_pos_col <- panel_cols(panel_table)
  if (switch_x) {
    if (!is.null(strips$x$bottom)) {
      if (inside_x) {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$bottom), -2)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$bottom, -2, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-b-", seq_along(strips$x$bottom)), z = 2)
      } else {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, strip_padding, -1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$bottom), -1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$bottom, -1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-b-", seq_along(strips$x$bottom)), z = 2)
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (!is.null(strips$x$top)) {
      if (inside_x) {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$top), 1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$top, 2, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-t-", seq_along(strips$x$top)), z = 2)
      } else {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, strip_padding, 0)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$top), 0)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$top, 1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-t-", seq_along(strips$x$top)), z = 2)
      }
    }
  }
  panel_pos_rows <- panel_rows(panel_table)
  if (switch_y) {
    if (!is.null(strips$y$left)) {
      if (inside_y) {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$left), 1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 2, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-l-", seq_along(strips$y$left)), z = 2)
      } else {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, strip_padding, 0)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$left), 0)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 1, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-l-", seq_along(strips$y$left)), z = 2)
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (!is.null(strips$y$right)) {
      if (inside_y) {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$right), -2)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -2, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-r-", seq_along(strips$y$right)), z = 2)
      } else {
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, strip_padding, -1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$right), -1)
        panel_table <- gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -1, clip = "on", 
                                       name = paste0("strip-r-", seq_along(strips$y$right)), z = 2)
      }
    }
  }
  panel_table
}
```

Continuing in new code block to stop the scrolling:

```
# need to pre-set the same environment to find things like e.g.
# gtable_matrix() from package gtable
environment(draw_panels_new) <- environment(FacetGrid$draw_panels)
# assign custom method
FacetGrid$draw_panels <- draw_panels_new

# happy plotting
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y, color = i)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(labely~labelx, scales = 'free_x', space = 'free_x')
```

I say shortcut because you could of course write your own version of `facet_grid_new` in addition, allowing you to pass the values `c(1,4)` from above flexibly as extra `params`.
And of course you could make your own `ggproto` object inheriting from `FacetGrid`...

---

**Edit:**

Another simple way of making this more flexible would be to add a custom `option`, e.g. like:

```
options(facet_size_manual = list(width = c(1,4), height = NULL))
```

This could then be used inside the custom `draw_panels` method somehow like this:

```
if (!is.null(facet_width <- getOption("facet_size_manual")$width))
  widths <- facet_width
```