# Break x axis to hide/ omit undesired/ similar observations

Tags: ggplot2, axis, break

I have a very big dataset (58000 rows) with which I want to plot temperature~ time(sec),
(measurement was done for 16 hours) using geom line or geom point. However between two specific time points( more then 8 hours) there is no change in temperature. It makes no sense to show them in very long geom line or
in big scatter points.  How can I break the x axis to hide the measurements between these two points?

```
Time/sec    temp
1            20
2            19.9
3            19.8
.            .
.            .
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ggplot2, can I insert a break in the axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis)