# How to add a point on the y-intercept (y-axis) using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot where the y-axis scaling changes at a certain point to plot data with some extreme values. I'm trying to add some sort of visual cue on the y-axis that indicates that the scaling changes at the point.

Here's an example of a plot

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(104)

ggdata <- data.frame('x' = rep('a',100),
                     'y' = c(runif(90, 0, 20), runif(10, 90, 100)))

transformation <- trans_new(
  "my_transformation", 
  transform = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30, x / 5, (x - 30) / 20 + 30 / 5),
  inverse = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30 / 5, x * 5, (x - 30 / 5) * 20 + 30)
)

ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))
```

[image: scatter plot]

I want to add some marker to "tick 30" on y axis for scale change.

I was thinking of adding a double tick on the axis, but there is no `linetype` that looks like a double line. The product should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wirxo.png). I'm aware of transforms like `scale_y_log10`, but I'd rather work with custom scaling that dynamically changes with the data.

EDIT: per @Tjebo's suggestion, I used `annotate` to add a "=" to the y axis breakpoint:

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(104)

ggdata <- data.frame('x' = rep('a',100),
                     'y' = c(runif(90, 0, 20), runif(10, 90, 100)))

transformation <- trans_new(
  "my_transformation", 
  transform = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30, x / 5, (x - 30) / 20 + 30 / 5),
  inverse = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30 / 5, x * 5, (x - 30 / 5) * 20 + 30)
)

mybreaks <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110)
tick_linetype <- rep("solid", length(mybreaks))
tick_linetype[4] <- "blank"

ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate(geom = "point", shape = "=", x = -Inf, y = 30, size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, breaks = mybreaks) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(linetype = tick_linetype)) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Here are some related topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis

Comment: @bs93 Thank you for the link. I guess producing two plots with & without the extreme values could be a solution. I'd like to see a way incorporate all information in one plot though. I'm working with genetic data so I would have tens of thousands of data, so the table wouldn't be an effective method. To be precise, the "scatterplot" I'm working wtih is a manhattan plot, and I'd like to see the distribution of lower -log10(pval) as well as the extreme values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of adding a double tick on the axis, but there is no
>   linetype that looks like a double line.

You can use any character as point shape. Also an equal sign, or back slash, etc.

For example:

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(104)

ggdata <- data.frame('x' = rep('a',100),
                     'y' = c(runif(90, 0, 20), runif(10, 90, 100)))

transformation <- trans_new(
  "my_transformation", 
  transform = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30, x / 5, (x - 30) / 20 + 30 / 5),
  inverse = function(x) ifelse(x <= 30 / 5, x * 5, (x - 30 / 5) * 20 + 30)
)

ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate(geom = "point", shape = "=", x = -Inf, y = 30, size = 8, color = 'red') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))+
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

I removed the clipping, but you can also leave it. The color was just chosen for highlighting.

Or, even better, use text annotation. You can then also change the angle - kind of nice.

```r
ggplot(data = ggdata) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = "=", x = -Inf, y = 30, size = 8, color = "red", angle = 45) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes thank you! This is the closest to what I've been looking for. I had no idea that I could set `x` in `annotate()` to `-Inf`, let alone including it does not change the overall x scale.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot get the exact look that you linked to, but perhaps some of these ideas are useful to you.

You can make your specified value a minor break, and add a line only to minor breaks (here I was unable to pick the exact value of 20, since that was already a major break, but perhaps you can play around with the numbers to get something you like):

```
ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, minor_breaks=20.05,breaks = c(0, 10,20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(1)
  )
```

[image]

Another option is to change the labels themselves. Here I have bolded and wrapped in `()` the 20 value, but you can add other symbols as well:

```
ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, minor_breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110),
                       breaks  = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110), labels=c(0, 10, expression(bold(("20"))), 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))
```

[image]

You can add a segment to the plot, which here isn't the prettiest option since the x axis isn't continuous, but perhaps it will spur ideas:

```
ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=-.01,y=19.5,xend=.01,yend=20.5),size=1.5)
```

[image]

Perhaps you could also just shade the bottom (or top) portion of your plot:

```
ggplot(data = ggdata,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = transformation,breaks = c(0, 10,20, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110))+
  annotate("rect", xmin = .4, xmax = 1.6, ymin = 0, ymax = 21,
           alpha = .2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts Dylan. In fact, we've had similar ideas :) ! Adding a horizontal line could cause some confusion just because I already have dashed lines indicating the p-values. For now, I've colored the axis red at the "break point". Although it doesn't intuitively say that the scale changes at that point, but it still stands out. I still think having a "/" or "X" mark on the axis would be more visually alarming.

Comment: @J.Lee, I just had an additional thought, where you could shade one area. This may not be too ugly with other lines, etc. in the plot. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should help with how you want your axis to look like. FWIW I would like to caution against breaking axes unless you explicitly tell your audience about them. In the code below I created two plots, one is for the data below 30 and the other data is for the extreme points (and remove its x axis and labels). Then I use plot.margin to set the plots margins so that they overlap a bit when I put them in a grid.arrange. You might have to mess with the margins to get the labels to line up.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(104)

ggdata <- data.frame('x' = rep('a',100),
                     'y' = c(runif(90, 0, 20), runif(10, 90, 100)))

p1 <- ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30,5), limits = c(0,30))+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,.83,0,1), "cm")) 




p2 <- ggplot(data = ggdata) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq(60,100,10), limits = c(60,100)) +
  scale_x_discrete()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,-0.1,1), "cm"))


grid.arrange(p2,p1)
```