# Is there a way to jump from x to 100 on a axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survminer

I want to plot data from survival analysis in R using the survial and survminer package.
My survival probability ranges from 0% to ca 5%. I want a graph that has the ylim set to 0 to 20 but should have a 100% on the axis, too.
Looking something like that:

[image]

I am doing this af the time:

```
    tlr_plot <- ggsurvplot(survFit_TLR, fun = "event", conf.int = FALSE, risk.table = 'nrisk_cumevents', title="TLR", legend = "none",  tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),surv.scale="percent")
tlr_plot$plot <- tlr_plot$plot +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,180,365,540,730), labels = c(0,180,365,540,730), limits=0:741) 
tlr_plot
```

Comment: Have you tried using a log scale?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56000944/3301344

Comment: That 100% looks like it would unnecessary and misleading to the viewer.