# Break or kink // in x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data= data,aes=(x=parameter,y= Count,fill=value)) + geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+ cord_flip()
```

I want to get break in x-axis like initially, I want scales to be 1,2,3,4,5 then a break followed by 5,10,15. Please refer the below figure for break or kink I am talking about

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is something which seems not to fit to plotting strategy of ggplot. It is a broadly discussed topic, if this should be done and what else could be used instead. Although there are other libraries (like plotrix) which can do this, in the ggplot area it is avoided to have breaks. A very interesting discussion can be found in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis). It points also to alternative and modern techniques like zooming with **ggforce** .

Comment: Or use a common transformation such as a log scale.