# Why I cannot change my y-axis values with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change my y-axis for a better view of the overplayed plots, with R, with ggplot2. As you can see Pakistan and United Kingdom in the first column, aren't readable

[image]

here is the code:

```
sympt_count_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(count_symptoms_positive_add, ggplot2::aes(x = age_band, y = Count, group = Symptoms, fill = Symptoms)) +
  ggplot2::geom_area( color = "white") +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", 
                                        "60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,
                                                                       2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000)) +
  ggplot2::labs(#title = "% of responders across countries",
    y = "Count", x = "Age band") +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(size = 17, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(size = 17),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", hjust = 0), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 1)

sympt_count_plot
```

I get an error of this kind:

```
Error in seq.default(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,  : 
  too many arguments
    In addition: Warning message:
    In seq.default(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 
        2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000) :
     extra arguments  will be disregarded
```

I have added the new values so that I would be able to see the plots better

And here is the data:

https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/blob/master/count_symptoms_showing_symptoms_add.csv

Is there a way to fix this?

Update - based on the answer bellow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you probably meant to do was `c(100,200,...)` instead of `seq(...)`.  Or `c(seq(0,1000,by=100),seq(2100,3000,by=100))`. But I suspect this will not do what you want; that is, the overall y-axis range of the plots will be the same as before, you will only be adjusting the spacing of the grid lines.  I would try **omitting** `scale_y_continuous()` (i.e., letting `ggplot` use its default algorithm for choosing axis breaks) and specifying a free y-scale in `facet_wrap()`, i.e.

```r
facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 1, scale="free_y")
```

[image]

Full code:

```r
count_symptoms_positive_add <- read.csv("SO65597881.csv")
library(ggplot2)
sympt_count_plot <- ggplot(count_symptoms_positive_add, aes(x = age_band, y = Count, group = Symptoms, fill = Symptoms)) +
  geom_area( color = "white") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", 
                                        "60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(#title = "% of responders across countries",
    y = "Count", x = "Age band") +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 17),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", hjust = 0), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 1, scale="free_y")

sympt_count_plot 
ggsave(type="cairo-png",file="sympt_count_plot.png")
```

Comment: I actually want to keep the same values to all of them. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want an axis break, i.e. the space between 1000 and 3000 is omitted? This is hard (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis ) and will be even harder with a derived plot like `geom_area()` ...

Comment: I totally get you. You're right here. is just that I was trying to make it uniform as I am adding another column, for comorbidities. and tried to have the same values across all overplayed plots including for the second column that will be added later.

Comment: c(seq(0,1000,by=100),seq(2100,3000,by=100)) - where exactly I pass this?

Comment: as your `breaks` argument (in place of `seq(...)`).  But I don't think you'll like the results.

Comment: I am trying to offer this as an alternative. As you are right, probably we cannot achieve what I want as per explanation in stack overflow link you have provided. However, I am not sure how you managed to get clear y-axis, I could not. Check the updated post with the new version of the picture.

Comment: the picture? with the second overplayed plots? Do you see it? It does say "Update - based on the version of code provided." But it is situated after your plot.

Comment: I didn't see that you had edited my answer.  Please edit **your question** to include this graph, not my answer ...

Comment: added to my post. Thank you

Comment: did not solve my issue with the y axis. Would you please put the whole code you have written in order to give the output?

Comment: @ Ben Bolker - I am hoping you saw the above last comment?