# ggplot2 - show only lower and upper range of y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

y-axis in my geom_dotplot ranges from 0 to 1. Dots are only in the upper and lower range. I want to shrink the intermediate range with no dots (0.05 - 0.95) into the interval 0.05 and display together with the lower range between 0 - 0.05 and the upper range 0.95-1.
Can anyone help, please?
my code is:

```
ggplot(
  identical, aes(x=SNV, y=RAF, fill=Mutual_zygosity_of_parents)) +
  geom_dotplot(
    binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', stackratio = 0, dotsize = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cadetblue1")) + 
  theme(legend.key=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold",size=16), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=16)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  expand_limits(x= c(-1,+195))
```

[image: plot]

Thanks a lot
Milos

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  As currently written, I believe your question will quickly attract down- and close-votes.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a discontinuous axis, where you are just skipping over a range of values that have no data. This has been asked before, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534248/how-can-i-make-a-discontinuous-axis-in-r-with-ggplot2 . If this is not what you are trying to do, please clarify how your request is different from those previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not reproducible since we don't have your data, but we can at least construct a similar data structure with the same names so we can use your plotting code to get a similar result:

```r
set.seed(1)

identical <- data.frame(SNV = factor(sample(1:200, 400, TRUE)),
                        RAF = c(runif(200, 0, 0.02), runif(200, 0.97, 1)),
                        Mutual_zygosity_of_parents = "Yes")

p <- ggplot(
  identical, aes(x=SNV, y=RAF, fill=Mutual_zygosity_of_parents)) +
  geom_dotplot(
    binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', stackratio = 0, dotsize = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cadetblue1")) + 
  theme(legend.key=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold",size=16), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=16)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  expand_limits(x= c(-1,+195))

p
```

[image]

Now the problem here is that ggplot cannot do discontinuous axes, but you can come fairly close by faceting. All we need to do is set the faceting variable as `RAF < 0.5`, which will split the upper and lower dots into their own groups. If we also use `scales = "free_y"`, then the y axis will "zoom in" to the range of the upper and lower dots:

```r
p + facet_grid(RAF < 0.5~., scales = "free_y")
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]