# How to change the thickness of a particular squares in geom_tile of y axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to scale a particular part of the y axis of a ggplot graph. The basic code is:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(val = rnorm(100), 
                 gene = rep(letters[1:20], 5), 
                 cell = c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5], 
                                 function(l) rep(l, 20))))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y = gene, x = cell, fill = val)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white")
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

And I need an output like:

[image: I need to scale particular rows of squares]

Maybe you have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Maybe these existing answers can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis. It's unclear exactly what type of different scaling you are expecting.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I want that the squares from the upper part have bigger dimensions than the lower ones.

Comment: But by how much? What determines when the change happens? How exactly do you want these axes labeled? Are distances preserved and you are just changing labels or are you actually trying to transform only part of the data in the graph?

Comment: Oh sorry. If you run the code you see all the characteristics of the basic plot. By how much will depend on other factors. But i need to find the way to change the thickness of them.

Comment: Or maybe i need to find another way to drawn the squares.