# Is there a way to shorten long intergenic regions in gggenes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, genome, gggenes

I'm visualizing a series of gene clusters with gggenes, and was wondering if there is a built-in functionality or workaround to shorten long, unannotated regions between genes of interest. Here's the set of genes giving me grief:

```
df<-data.frame(start=c(594198,596540,598457,600085,983488,984345),
stop=c(596450,598423,600070,601182,984336,986495),
species=rep("Ferriphaselus amnicola",6),
gene=c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5","gene6"))
```

When you use gggenes to visualize this, you get something not so pretty:

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, y = species, fill = gene)) +
    geom_gene_arrow() +
    facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
    theme_genes()
```

[image]

Ideally, I"d be able to tell gggenes that when there are more than x number of nucleotides between 2 genes, replace that span of genome with two slashes (as is customary in the literature). I'm imagining something like this edit I cobbled together in powerpoint:
[image]

Is there a straightforward way to do this in gggenes, or even in another package?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This one is really hacky and with a lot of code by hand. But as a starting point it could help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Define common components
arrow_geom <- list(
  geom_gene_arrow(
    arrowhead_height = unit(12, "mm"),
    arrowhead_width = unit(6, "mm"),
    arrow_body_height = unit(6, "mm")
  ),
  geom_gene_label(aes(label = gene), height = unit(6, "mm"), grow = TRUE)
)

common_theme <- theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=20),
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm")
  )

# Plot with legend
p0 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, y = species, fill = gene)) +
  arrow_geom +
  facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  common_theme

# Extract the legend
legend <- get_legend(p0)

# Plot for gene1 to gene4
p1 <- df %>%
  mutate(median_stop = median(stop)) %>%
  filter(stop > (median_stop - 10000) & stop < (median_stop + 10000)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, y = species, fill = gene)) +
  arrow_geom +
  facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  labs(y="") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  common_theme

# Plot for gene5 to gene6
p2 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = median(stop)) %>%
  filter(stop > x + 100000) %>%
  mutate(species = "") %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, y = species, fill = gene)) +
  arrow_geom +
  facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "orange")) +
  labs(y = "") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  common_theme +
  theme(
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank()
  )


dev.off()

# set the margins and combine all
p1 <- p1 + theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm")) 
p2 <- p2 + theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm"))
g <- arrangeGrob(
  p1, p2, legend,
  nrow = 1,
  widths = c(4, 2, 1)  
)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google for an axis-breaking option brought up the ggbreak package:

```
install.packages("ggbreak")
library(ggbreak)
```

It took a bit of fiddling to narrow down the proper breakpoints but this looks promising. Assuming you assigned your plot object to the name `plt`:

```
library(ggbreak); (plt2 <- plt + scale_x_break(c(6.05e+05, 9.8e+05)) )
```

[image]

After the first instance of fiddling I started getting warnings, but plots were still produced.

> In Summary.unit(list(list(0, NULL, 8L), list(1, list(list(1, list( :
> reached elapsed time limit

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of gggenes. You can't do this within gggenes. However, you can still achieve this with ggplot2 in a few different ways:

- You could generate separate plots for each CDS region and compose them with [the patchwork package](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com)
- As IRTFM suggested, you could use [the ggbreak package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html) to insert axis breaks, although note that broken axes are [somewhat frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) as they distort the mapping between data and plot aesthetics and can be misleading
- I wrote [a package called ggwrap](https://github.com/wilkox/ggwrap) which takes a wide plot and wraps it over multiple rows, originally intended for plotting long sequences with gggenes